# Angular: Replacing a class instance causes data binding to fail

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular 10

A general question that I've had in a number of situations and that would be good to get around.

I commonly create a class instance on a page and assign it to a variable.  e.g.

`this.myProject: Project = new Project();`

I then bind that to page elements:

`<app-my-component [project]="myProject"></app-my-component>`

I then need to update the `this.myProject` object and so re-assign it:

`this.myProject = AN_UPDATED_PROJECT_CLASS_INSTANCE`

Most times the binding in the `app-my-component` continues to work and will reflect the updated values in the newly assigned `Project` class instance "AN_UPDATED_PROJECT_CLASS_INSTANCE".

However, there are times when the binding breaks.  For example if I use [ng-bootstraps modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) and have the modal window popped up and update the `this.myProject` it doesn't bind all the way through to the modal window and the original properties remain.

I'm assuming that this is because I am actually **replacing** the object referenced in memory by `this.myProject` with an entirely new object.  If I **update** the properties one by one the binding works properly.  However, clearly this is impractical for complex class structures.

I have found the [lodash merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge) function which appears to update the object rather than replace it and propagates the changes.

`merge(this.myProject, AN_UPDATED_PROJECT_CLASS_INSTANCE);`

Is this a good/proper solution?

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing a minimal reproduction on stackblitz. In general - ChangeDetection should take care of that IF you're using `@Input` / `@Output` (and not using OnPush strategy). Also, you shouldn't be forced to change properties instead of assigning new objects. So you should look for the underlying issue in the code instead of using some strange workaround.

Comment: Yes.  That's kinda why I was asking.  I want to find the root cause for the issue.

Comment: I've forked the demo from the ng-bootstrap and added timer that changes the reference after the the modal is displayed and everything works fine - see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tojkvq). If you want us to help you find your issue, provide minimal reproduction on stackblitz and we'll work from there.

Answer (score 1):

Something to consider first, is `myProject` overloaded with too many responsibilities? Maybe start by splitting those concerns into different objects/input variables that will properly trigger change detection the minimum necessary times.

As for triggering change detection with complex objects, you have a few options.

1. Clone the object to create a new reference

```js
# Using the spread operator
this.myProject = {...AN_UPDATED_PROJECT_CLASS_INSTANCE};
# Using object assign
this.myProject = Object.assign({}, AN_UPDATED_PROJECT_CLASS_INSTANCE);
```

2. Use an observable

```js
this.myProject$ = new BehaviorSubject<Project>(new Project());
```

Template:

```html
<app-my-component [project]="myProject$ | async"></app-my-component>
```

Updating:

```js
this.myProject$.next(AN_UPDATED_PROJECT_CLASS_INSTANCE);
```

3. Trigger change detection manually

```js
constructure(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

someMethod() {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Some interesting approaches here.  Appreciated.

Comment: Could you please up-vote or accept my answer if it was useful?

Comment: Thanks.  I've upvoted it.  It doesn't completely answer my question though.  Is it the fact that I'm replacing the object rather than updating it that causes the data binding to fail.  It appears that way.  Much appreciated.